# Поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: c++

Как можно найти подстроку введенной строки в С++? Например, я ввел строку: "Hello World", потом ввожу "llo" и если во введенной строке первой есть такая подстрока, то пусть выведет `true`. Вот такое что-то нужно создать, но не знаю, как давать поиск в строке на совпадение.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать стандартные средства языка или реализовать эффективный алгоритм? Если первое - то вам ответили ниже, если второе, то скорее всего стоит начать [отсюда](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: Согласен с тем что выше - сам копался в этой тем и пришел к аналогичному в примере выходу.

Answer (score 12):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello world";
    size_t pos = s.find("ell");
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "Found at pos = " << pos << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

man strstr

> Возвращает указатель на первое вхождение строки поиска в строке.

Comment: а можно поподробнее? А то это как то очень коротко и непонятно

Comment: Если строка -- это string, то лучше не надо. strstr работает с char* , к которым string надо ещё преобразовывать. См. ответ @gkuznets